# How to convert pngBytes into file for pass into data-form

Tags: api, flutter, dart, lumen, uint8list

```
Future<void> _capturePng() async {
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
setState(() {
  data = pngBytes;
});
```

}

How to convert this pngbytes into file for pass into data form ?

```
FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
  "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(image.path,filename: image.path.split("/").last),
  "signature": await MultipartFile.fromFile(here),
  "latitude": "${_currentPosition.latitude}, ${_currentPosition.longitude}",
});
```

Comment: Why not use `MultipartFile.fromBytes`?

Comment: Still can't, the Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'.

Comment: Are you passing the _bytes_ to `MultipartFile.fromBytes`?